# Adding new attribute to existing xml file using sed or awk

Tags: linux, xml

I have a xml file which contains below details:

```
<server>
  <mbean code="WSMQConnectionFactory" name="service=MQQueueConnectionFactory">
  <attribute name="JndiName">WSMQQueueConnectionFactory</attribute> 
  <attribute name="QueueManagerName">QMPMP</attribute>
  <attribute name="HostName">10.10.20.21</attribute>  
  <attribute name="Channel">CHANNEL01</attribute> 
  <attribute name="TransportType">MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP</attribute> 
  <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends> 
 </mbean>
</server>
```

I want to search for a "HostName" attribute and add new attribute(port) after it. It should look like this :

```
<server>
  <mbean code="WSMQConnectionFactory" name="service=MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <attribute name="JndiName">WSMQQueueConnectionFactory</attribute> 
    <attribute name="QueueManagerName">QMPMP</attribute>
    <attribute name="HostName">10.10.20.21</attribute> 
    <attribute name="Port">1414</attribute> 
    <attribute name="Channel">CHANNEL01</attribute>
    <attribute name="TransportType">MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP</attribute> 
    <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends> 
  </mbean>
  </server>
```

Please suggest

Comment: Obligatory link: [You can't parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5419599).

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this. XML is a structured data type, and it's one that doesn't 'fit' a regular expression. Whilst you can pretend your XML is plain text, and use e.g. 'sed' to adjust it, this is a very good way of creating brittle code - because different XML structures that are semantically identical *won't work* in the same way.

To do this, you really need a parser. I would suggest Perl (which is ubiquitous) and `XML::Twig` which is quite common and easily installed.

This code will do it (it's a little longer than it actually *needs* to be, but this is in the interests of clarity).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub paste_port {
    my ( $twig, $attribute ) = @_;
    my $port_attr =
        XML::Twig::Elt->new( 'attribute', { 'name' => 'Port' }, 1414 );
    print "Inserting:\n", $port_attr->sprint, "\n";
    $port_attr->paste_after($attribute);
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented',
    'twig_handlers' => { 'attribute[@name="HostName"]', \&paste_port }
);
$twig->parsefile('your_xml.xml');
$twig->print;

#save to file 'new_xml.xml'
open( my $output_file, ">", "new_xml.xml" ) or warn $!;
print {$output_file} $twig->sprint;
close($output_file);
```

This will produce the output:

```
<server>
  <mbean code="WSMQConnectionFactory" name="service=MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <attribute name="JndiName">WSMQQueueConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <attribute name="QueueManagerName">QMPMP</attribute>
    <attribute name="HostName">10.10.20.21</attribute>
    <attribute name="Port">1414</attribute>
    <attribute name="Channel">CHANNEL01</attribute>
    <attribute name="TransportType">MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP</attribute>
    <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
  </mbean>
</server>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
sed -i -r 's/(.*HostName.*)/\1\n<attribute name="Port">1414<\/attribute>/g' filename
```

Result in:

```
$ cat filename
<server>
  <mbean code="WSMQConnectionFactory" name="service=MQQueueConnectionFactory">
  <attribute name="JndiName">WSMQQueueConnectionFactory</attribute>
  <attribute name="QueueManagerName">QMPMP</attribute>
  <attribute name="HostName">10.10.20.21</attribute>
<attribute name="Port">1414</attribute>
  <attribute name="Channel">CHANNEL01</attribute>
  <attribute name="TransportType">MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP</attribute>
  <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
 </mbean>
</server>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but I am getting below output when using it.
-bash-2.05b# sed -i -E 's/(.*HostName.*)/\1\n<attribute name="Port">1414<\/attribute>/g' /home/ittcsc/jboss-service.xml
sed: invalid option -- E
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space
  -e script, --expression=script
                 add the script to the commands to be executed

Comment: Replacing `-E` with `-r` should work in that case. If won't work, paste the output of `bash --version`.